# Force two divs to move together when either is dragged using jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ztjfmud/6/).

I need to have the two "linked" divs (which have ID's that are identical except for a suffix A and B) move in unison when dragged. I'm trying to write JS to handle this without going into the jquery ui library and messing it up. After reading the various option flags [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), there doesn't appear to be a simple way to handle this.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="template ui-sortable" id="template_epsemail_email">
        <div class="tmplcell moveable ui-sortable-handle" id="tmplchunk_1"> unlinked </div>
        <div class="tmplcell moveable ui-sortable-handle" id="tmplchunk_2"> unlinked </div>
        <div class="tmplcell moveable ui-sortable-handle" id="tmplchunk_3_A"> linked </div>
        <div class="tmplcell moveable ui-sortable-handle" id="tmplchunk_3_B"> linked </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.template').sortable({
        containment: 'body',
        axis: 'y',
        items: '.tmplcell.moveable',
      });
});
```

Comment: My mistake. Some possibilities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items), but you don't have list items so I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596748/sort-multiple-items-at-once-with-jquery-ui-sortable). I think a helper function is your ticket.

Comment: There is not a simple way to do this. You can leverage `helper: function()` to build a grouped element.

Comment: I was just looking at the `start: function()` flag and that seems like it may work better since `helper` is expected to return something. I can slice off the last two characters of my ID's and check for matches, that way the two "linked" divs are grouped. But from there, I need to find out how that group gets moved in unison.

Comment: @JacobIRR still think the helper would work for you to create an element that contains both items.

Comment: Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1r2b605a/